# Declarative support for sub-items

Tags: angular

Not talking much about motivation today, so I'll go straight into the matter in question. The following works fine in angular:

```
<grid [columns]="Columns">
</grid>
```

I am not quite happy with defining the columns in code, though. What I'm looking for is an approach like the following:

```
<grid>
   <columns>
     <textcolumn datamember="P1" name="Property 1"></textcolumn>
     <templatecolumn>
          <a [routerLink]="['/', '##P2.value##']">##P2.Name##</a>
     </templatecolumn>
   </columns>
</grid>
```

Is something like this (using an element's content to set array property) even possible with angular?

The template parsing bit is already solved, since I have to do it for the code based version as well.

Comment: That's what material's cdk table is doing, isn't it? https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview

Comment: Yup, quite similar